# Recover ec2 root password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, password-recovery

Last week I changed the root password of our Centos ec2 instance and now I've forgotten what the new password is. I can SSH into the machine using my user account without a key, I disabled it in SSH configuration before and I have access to the AWS account dashboard. Also this user account is in the sudoers file but unfortunately I can't remember the password too. This VM runs our website and database and we cannot afford to loose access to it. I appreciate your help tho

Comment: So you lost both sudo password and root password?

Comment: exactly, but still can ssh to the instance, I used copy-ssh-key before so it don't ask me for a password while connecting it.

Comment: The default ec2 user should be able to run `sudo su -` without entering password and gaining root access. Are you not able to gain root access like that?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Which user are you using? ec2_user?

Comment: centos, I don't have ec2-user on this instance

Comment: AWS has fantastic help online. Here's the appropriate master article which links to options for you https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-access-lost-key-pair/

Answer (score 0):

By default, you should be able to switch to the root user using this command:

```
sudo su -
```

The above shouldn't ask for your password.